# Angular 4 routing duplicate component for a particular path

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-mdl

I have a weird problem , that when a particular route is directly launched the component is added twice in the dom, but when navigated from main page it works fine.

The problem is with `contact` route `ContactComponent`

You can check that live on this website

1. Go to http://ootybookings.in/#/main/contact
2. You can see the contact component added twice
3. Now click on Home Menu/Link at top and then Click Contact Menu/Link
4. Now the duplicate is gone

All other routes are fine. Only contact route is making this problem.

Config

```
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
```

Routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'welcome',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'welcome',
    component: WelcomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'tour-packages',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'tour-packages',
        component: TourPackagesComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'tour-package/:name',
        component: TourPackageDetailComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'activities',
        component: ActivitiesComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        component: ContactComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'who-we-are',
        component: WhoWeAreComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'why-ooty',
        component: WhyOotyComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'services',
        component: TourServicesComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'blogs',
        component: BlogComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'blog/:name',
        component: BlogDetailComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'offers',
        component: OffersComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'terms',
        component: TermsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'privacy',
        component: PrivacyPolicyComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'refund',
        component: RefundPolicyComponent
      }

    ]
  }
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

How can I resolve this? Is there a problem with my routing module? I've checked similar questions on SO and other sites, but I cannot find a solution.

Comment: This normally occurs when the compiler runs into an error, and isn't linked to routing. I'm seeing tons of console errors, so I'm guessing it's related to compilation error.

Comment: @Z.Bagley Compilation errors will be shown beforehand. This is not that. Those console errors you see are warnings due to google maps.

Comment: @Madhan, did you try debugging with anableTracing , one issue may be the contact route defined in two places - https://angular.io/guide/router#remove-duplicate-hero-routes

Comment: Run time error that can occur when the angular compiler (either downloaded by client, or running on the server) breaks (errors). The duplication is _normally_ because angular compiler is failing to properly render the DOM. Likely due to an element's directive not writing properly, or a viewchild w/ an async that's not loading correct, etc. Run into this often, and never had routing the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I guess routing is not the problem, I'm using [Angular Mdl](http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl/)

I've mentioned `<dialog-outlet></dialog-outlet>`(needed for Mdl dialogs) in two different places, which lead to this issue. Don't know why it affected a particular component. After removing that, the route works fine.